# Moving values from Excel column to Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create macro in Access VBA that open Excel file and then directly move values from Excel cells to  Access records. From example it takes values from columns in row two - copy them into columns counterpart in Access and then go to the new row and record. I search for some solution in Internet, and I found that probabely the best way to do it, is by using SQL, but I am pretty new in this topic and it will be really helpfull if you can bring me some example that I can work on.

Best regards, 
Robert

Answer (score 0):

You could use transferspreadsheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Sheet1", filename, True
```

Then use an append query or a make table query to collect the data from your spreadsheet. Here is the SQL for a Make-Table query:

```
SELECT Sheet1.* INTO ExcelData
FROM Sheet1;
```